# Clustering User-Input Markers (Google Maps x Android Studio)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, user-input, markerclusterer

I am trying to cluster markers that users input onMapLongClick but I can't seem to figure it out. All the tutorials/samples I've found show how to cluster for objects that are at a predetermined LatLng. This won't work for what I want to do because the point is not known until the user places a marker. For example, if users input twenty markers while using the app in a certain location at zoom level 7, then I want to be able to cluster them based on distance or a grid or however when they zoom to level 6. I am using Google Maps with Android Studio. Can anyone please help? I've been working for awhile on this...Here is the code I have so far. Thank you!

```
public class BasicMapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap mMap;
private UiSettings mUiSettings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_legal) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LegalInfoActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    mMap = map;
    mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point)
                    .snippet("this is a snippet"));
        }
    });


    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            float maxZoom = 7.0f;
            if (position.zoom > maxZoom) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(maxZoom));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to attach a `ClusterManager` to your map. It will automatically animate the markers from cluster at their position (or cluster them, when you zoom out).

The clustering is part of another project, called `android-map-utils` which can be found here:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

They have a great demo application in the repository, I believe you will find the functionality you need there.

Example for adding items to `ClusterManager`, after you map has been initialised.

1. set up the cluster manager

   ```
   mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(BrowseLocationsActivity.this, googleMap);
   mClusterManager.setClusterOnlyVisibleArea(true);
   mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new VisibleNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<MapMarkerItem>(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));
   ```
2. when you need to add a new item to your cluster, just call

   ```
   mClusterManager.addItem(new MapMarkerItem(latitude, longitude));
   mClusterManager.cluster();
   ```

Note that`MapMarkerItem` is a custom class, that implementes `ClusterItem` from the library.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have downloaded that and looked at it however I believe all the demos in the android-maps-utils cluster based on markers that have been input prior to a user putting them in onMapLongClick. The user-input side of things is where I believe I am getting hung up...

Comment: You can add items dynamically items to the ClusterManager. I will edit my answer to add a few lines of code from my project

Comment: added an example, on how you can simply use the cluster. you don't need mode than that for what you want to achieve

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand your response. When I put it into my code (and change it to BasicMapDemoActivity.this and mMap to fit my project) it can't resolve mClusterManager and <MapMarkerItem> and metrics. Also I won't be the one adding items to the cluster. The person using the app will be adding markers when they LongClick...Sorry for the confusion I'm new at developing apps. I appreciate your help!

Comment: 1. you need to import the android-map-utils project first, to be able to use the ClusterManager
2. BasicMapDemoActivity.this was a copy-paste from my example. You need a context object.
3. you have a general action: adding a new marker to the clustermanager. you can do that at any point in your application, including in the body of longClick. latitude and longitude from the MapMarkerItem constructor, will be the coordinates where the users clicks.

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing. I imported "import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;" then I added "private ClusterManager mClusterManager;" to the top to be able to add the mClusterManager. The code still said that it couldn't resolve <MapMarkerItem> and metrics. It also couldn't resolve the latitude and longitude in the second part...Sorry this is going over my head right now.

Comment: I also imported the NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm but that's also saying it's unable to resolve it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...